# What are the chances of a paper being accepted after

Tags: peer-review, journal-workflow

I got minor revision in the first round of review. The main concern of the reviewer was to add the details in methods section and some amendments in the text. I re-submitted the paper after incorporating these changes in the manuscript (I work in Biology field). But the status of the paper is showing  "under review" again. Does it mean the manuscript will go through peer review again? what are the chances of the paper being accepted? Please help..

Comment: There is no conceivable way for anyone to answer this given we know nothing about the papers content, the journal you're applying to or the field you're in. It's under review again, meaning they're looking at your revisions to evaluate if they want to publish it.

Comment: like what @Eppicurt said, it's hard to tell without knowing the details, but if after the first round of review, the verdict is "minor revision", and you've done what the reviewers suggested, then I would say it has a good chance of being accepted (this is from my own experience both as author and reviewer, but NOT in biology field), worst case you probably have to revise again. In either case, I won't worry about the "under review" status.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the manuscript is going through peer review again depends on the editorial manager system the journal is using. If the status goes something like "submitted to journal" -> "editor assigned" -> "under review", then yes, it means your paper is going through peer review again. If it goes "submitted to journal" -> "under review" (i.e. it doesn't tell you that an editor has been assigned), then there's no way to tell until you receive a decision. A quick decision implies it didn't go through peer review again; a slow one and / or reviewer comments indicates it did.

There's no way to be sure if the the paper is likely to be accepted without knowing more about the paper's content & the review. However, based on your description, chances are good it'll be accepted eventually. If the corrections are minor and you've performed them, there's no reason for rejection.